# Help identifying MOV

Tags: varistor, mov

Need some help in  Identifying MOV[image: pic of MOV]
ZNR
E14221
RU068

Answer (score 5):

*Similar* to Panasonic [ERZE14A221](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/AWA0000/AWA0000C18.pdf). Probably **not** original (i.e. a clone from another manufacturer) since it lacks the Panasonic/Matsushita (or any) logo.

That would be a 220V MOV (max 140VAC, so for 120VAC use) with a diameter of about 16.5mm (internal disk is likely 14mm).

Answer (score 3):

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADIN1300.pdf

[image]

14 221 means 14mm internal disc, 220Vac  rated for 1W or  155J 1200pF impulse.

Avail. at Mouser et al.
https://www.mouser.ca/c/?q=ERZE14A221